# How to compare request string with last inserted row in the table using laravel Rule facade

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.8

I have custom code where validating phone confirm code:

**Code:**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request, [
    'confirm_code' => [
        'required',
        Rule::exists('confirm_codes')->where(function($query) use($request) {
            $query->where('phone', $request->phone)
                  ->where('confirm_code', $request->confirm_code)
        })
    ]
]);
```

This validation work but check existing any confirm code which phone equal to request phone. But I need check request confirm code with the **last** insrted confirm code by **date** from `confirm_codes` table which phone equal to request phone.

**Tried:**

```
Rule::exists('confirm_codes')->where(function($query) use($request) {
    $query->where('phone', $request->phone)
          ->where('confirm_code', $request->confirm_code)
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');                          // added this line <--
})
```

But this solution not work. How I can do like this validation using `Rule` facade?

Comment: You are *not* passing `$data` to the Closure

Comment: Yes passed in my local code. I forgot in my question. I now will edit question @linktoahref

Comment: I think you need to create a custom rule to validate against a single record, as adding a orderby clause wouldn't have any effect in a  exists rule.

Comment: did you try with the method last() instead using orderby, or adding method first() after the orderby method ?

Comment: It's not impossible inside `Rule::exists()` method @rüff0

Comment: Generally I can't solve this problem using `Rule` facade? @linktoahref

Comment: Are you after the last row with a specific phone/code or just the actual last row in the database?

Comment: With a specific phone/code @Rwd

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom rule using a [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#using-closures):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request, [
    'confirm_code' => [
        'required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {

            $latest = DB::table('confirm_codes')->latest()->first();

            if ($request->phone === $latest->phone && $value === $latest->confirm_code) {
                $fail('[enter your error message here]');
            }

        },
    ],
]);
```